# Thin restart in Capistrano doesn't pickup changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, restart, thin

Using `after 'deploy:publishing', 'thin:restart'` in `deploy.rb` doesn't work as expected. For unknow reason, thin server doesn't pickup changes.

Even when I run manualy `thin:restart` in console on server after deploy is done nothing changes. I have to stop and start server again to see changes (`thin stop && thin start`).

I do not use any cache. All files are changed when I `vi` them. Looks like thin server is still using files from previous release. Like he has path set to last release and ignores where `current` symlink points to.

I was trying to run `thin:restart` wrapped with `within release_path` and `within current_path` but no changes. And it doesn't suprise me as `thin:restart` in console doesn't work as well…

And if I do not use Capistrano all works fine. Restart on thin pickups all changes. So it is definetely related to capistrano and path problems.

Anyone had similar issue?

Comment: That the task is `thin:restart`? Is the manually restarting works? `bundle exec thin -C /path/to/thin.confg restart`

Comment: No, manual restarting is not working as I wrote in my post.

Comment: The problem is still present up to date. I haven't find the solution.